# Double Map Marker with double respective InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two Google map auto complete input for two location search.I have also able to manage 2 markers on that two places.But i have a for also that takes input of name(username).That name should be displayed on the infowindow of both markers.But one marker shows infoWindow and another marker shows no window.An the marker that showing infoWindow is not showing Username.

### Below is my HTML codes

```
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="StateSide Guess">
    <input id="pac-input2" type="text" placeholder="Foreign Guess">
  </div>
  <div>
    <form action="" class="guess-submit" style="text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <input type="hidden" id="state" name="state" />
        <input type="hidden" id="stateLat" name="stateLat" />
        <input type="hidden" id="stateLng" name="stateLng" />

        <input type="hidden" id="foreign" name="foreign" />
        <input type="hidden" id="foreignLat" name="foreignLat" />
        <input type="hidden" id="foreignLng" name="foreignLng" />  
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
    </form>  
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<div id="infowindow-content2">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon2">
  <span id="place-name2"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address2"></span>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqa9_oFYP4yorGy17BILIALjiqKXByoeE&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

### And below is javascript codes

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
          lat: 59.325,
          lng: 18.070
      },
      zoom: 9
  });
  var card    = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input   = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var input2  = document.getElementById('pac-input2');

  var username    = document.getElementById('name').value;

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  autocomplete2.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  var infowindowContent2 = document.getElementById('infowindow-content2');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {
          lat: 59.325,
          lng: 18.070
      },
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: {
          lat: 50.325,
          lng: 24.070
      },
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker2.setVisible(false);
      var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();
      document.getElementById('foreign').value = place2.name;
      document.getElementById('foreignLat').value = place2.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById('foreignLng').value = place2.geometry.location.lng();


      if (place2.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place2.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
          map.setCenter(place2.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(9);
      }
      marker2.setPosition(place2.geometry.location);
      marker2.setVisible(true);

      infowindowContent2.children['place-name2'].textContent = username;
      infowindow.open(map, marker2);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      document.getElementById('state').value = place.name;
      document.getElementById('stateLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
      document.getElementById('stateLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(9);
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = username;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

### And Below is the screenshot

[Google Map Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfnA9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached this a little differently after seeing what appears to be a lot of duplicated code - esecially when the end functionality is more or less the same for either autocomplete. To accomplish this I removed many of the ID attributes assigned to DOM elements and instead opted for `dataset` attributes instead which can be targeted using either of the `querySelector(All)` methods.

I put several comments throughout - this method could also be used for more than two location input fields simply by adding a new such input element within the correct parent container `pac-container` and assign similar attributes with associated infowindow content etc etc.

Anyway, it passed some time on a boring sunday, hope it is of use.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Maps - two autocomplete</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script async defer src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqa9_oFYP4yorGy17BILIALjiqKXByoeE&libraries=places&callback=initMap'></script>
        <script>
            function initMap(){
                /* some variables */
                var autocomplete;
                var infowindow;
                var marker;
                var options;
                var place;
                var obj;
                var url;
                var img;


                /* DOM elements */
                var oDiv     = document.getElementById('map');
                var oCard    = document.getElementById('pac-card');
                var oColInput= document.querySelectorAll('div#pac-container > input[data-type]');
                var oUsername= document.getElementById('name');



                /* Map initial config */
                options={
                    center: {
                        lat: 59.325,
                        lng: 18.070
                    },
                    zoom: 9                 
                };
                /* the map */
                var map = new google.maps.Map( oDiv, options );

                /*
                    Define objects associated with each of the input elements
                    used for places.

                    Each object created has a reference stored in `obj` which is
                    used as a bound object to the event listener so that each item
                    can be accessed within the listener using `this`
                */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( oColInput ).forEach( function( input ){
                    /* options for the autocomplete service */
                    options={
                        strictBounds: false
                    };

                    /* create the autocomplete object */
                    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
                    autocomplete.bindTo( 'bounds', map );

                    /* create the infowindow bound to this autocomplete object */
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow( { maxWidth:320, disableAutoPan:false } );
                    infowindow.setContent( document.querySelector('div.iwin[ data-type="'+input.dataset.type+'" ]') );

                    /* ensure hidden content from infowindow does not alter layout */
                    google.maps.event.addListener( infowindow, 'closeclick', function( event ){
                        this.getContent().style.display='none';
                    }.bind( infowindow ));

                    /* add a marker bound to the autocomplete service */
                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: {
                            lat: parseFloat( input.dataset.lat ),
                            lng: parseFloat( input.dataset.lng )
                        },
                        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
                    });

                    /* Marker events */
                    google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function(e){
                        this.open( map );
                        this.getContent().style.display='block';
                        this.setPosition( e.latLng );
                        this.setOptions( { pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(0,-32) } );
                    }.bind( infowindow ) );


                    /* 
                        add a reference to each object to our binding object used below
                    */
                    obj={
                        'input':input,
                        'type':input.dataset.type,
                        'marker':marker,
                        'autocomplete':autocomplete,
                        'infowindow':infowindow
                    }



                    /* Listen for changes and do some cool things */
                    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed',function(){
                        /* must have a username value to continue as it should appear on the infowindow */
                        if( oUsername.value=='' ){

                            oUsername.classList.add('warn');

                            setTimeout( function(){
                                this.input.value='';
                                oUsername.classList.remove('warn');
                            }.bind( this ),1500);

                            return;
                        }
                        /* reset existing marker if it exists */
                        this.marker.setVisible( false );
                        this.marker.title='';

                        var oWin=this.infowindow.getContent();
                            oWin.style.display='block';

                        place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
                        console.info( place );

                        /* find suitable hidden inputs within form - using span as parent */
                        var oSpan=document.querySelector('form > span[ id="'+this.type+'" ]');
                            oSpan.querySelector('input[ data-id="name" ]').value=this.input.value=='' ? '' : place.name;
                            oSpan.querySelector('input[ data-id="lat" ]').value=this.input.value=='' ? '' : place.geometry.location.lat();
                            oSpan.querySelector('input[ data-id="lng" ]').value=this.input.value=='' ? '' : place.geometry.location.lng();

                        if( place.geometry.viewport ) {
                            map.fitBounds( place.geometry.viewport );
                        } else {
                            map.setCenter( place.geometry.location );
                            map.setZoom(9);
                        }

                        this.marker.setPosition( place.geometry.location );
                        this.marker.setVisible( true );
                        this.marker.title=place.name;




                        /* find infowindow content & append new values */
                        oWin.querySelector('span[data-id="user-name"]').innerHTML=oUsername.value;
                        oWin.querySelector('span[data-id="place-name"]').innerHTML=place.name;
                        oWin.querySelector('span[data-id="place-address"]').innerHTML=place.formatted_address;

                        if( oWin.querySelector( 'a[data-id="'+this.type+'"]' ) ) oWin.removeChild( oWin.querySelector( 'a[data-id="'+this.type+'"]' ) );

                        var a=document.createElement('a');
                            a.dataset.id=this.type;
                            a.innerHTML='more...';
                            a.target='_blank';
                            a.href=place.url;

                        oWin.appendChild( a );

                        /* open the infowindow and show new content */
                        this.infowindow.open( map, this.marker );
                    }.bind( obj ));/* bind all the objects */
                });
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                height:100vh;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px
            }
            #map{
                width:800px;
                height:600px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
            .iwin{/* hidden infowindow content elements */
                display:none;
                width:320px;
                height:240px;
                padding:1rem;
                border:1px solid gray;
                border-radius:1rem;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;
            }
            .iwin > img{
                display:inline-block;
                clear:none;
                margin:0.5rem;
                float:left;
                outline:1px dotted rgba(133,133,133,0.25);
                padding:0.1rem;
                min-width:80px;
                min-height:120px;
            }
            .iwin > span{
                float:left;
                min-width:51%;
                margin:0 auto 0.25rem auto;
                display:inline-block;
                clear:right;
                color:gray;
            }
            .iwin > span[data-id='user-name']{
                font-size:1.25rem;
                font-weight:bold;
                color:green;
            }
            .iwin > span[data-id='place-name']{
                font-size:1rem;
            }
            .iwin > span[data-id='place-address']{
                font-size:0.9rem;
            }
            .iwin > a{
                float:right;
                margin:1rem auto;
                font-size:0.75rem;
            }







            #pac-card{
                width:800px;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
                padding:1rem;
                border:1px solid gray;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                display:flex;
                justify-content:space-around;
            }
            form{
                display:inline-block;
                clear:none;
                width:100%;
            }

            #pac-card > div {
                box-sizing:border-box;
                background:white;
                clear:none;
                margin:0;
                float:none;
                display:block;
            }
            input[type='text'],
            input[type='submit']{
                padding:1rem;
            }
            input[type='text'],
            #name{
                border:1px solid gray;
            }
            .warn{
                border:1px solid red!important;
                background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
                color:white;
            }
            input[value]:not([value=""]) + span:before{
                color:green;
                background:transparent;

                padding:0.25rem;
                clear:none;
                content:'L';
                display:inline-block;

                font-family: arial;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-size:1.5rem;

                -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
                -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
                transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);

                z-index:2;
                position:relative;
                left:-28rem!important;
            }

            input[type='submit']{
                text-transform:uppercase;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- // more or less original html content - less ID attributes but extensive use of dataset attributes // -->


        <div class='pac-card' id='pac-card'>
          <div id='pac-container'>
            <input data-type='stateside' data-lat='59.325' data-lng='18.070' type='text' placeholder='StateSide Guess' value='' />
            <input data-type='foreign' data-lat='50.325' data-lng='24.070' type='text' placeholder='Foreign Guess' value='' />
          </div>
          <div>
            <form class='guess-submit' style='text-align: center'>

                <span id='stateside'>
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='name' name='state' value='' /><span></span>
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='lat' name='stateLat' value='' />
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='lng' name='stateLng' value='' />
                </span>

                <span id='foreign'>
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='name' name='foreign' value='' /><span></span>
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='lat' name='foreignLat' value='' />
                    <input type='hidden' data-id='lng' name='foreignLng' value='' />
                </span>

                <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder='Your Name' />
                <input type='submit' id='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='submit' />
            </form>  
          </div>
        </div>


        <div id='map'></div>


        <!-- hidden elements - infowindow contents -->
        <div id='win_1' class='iwin' data-type='stateside'>
          <img src='' width='16' height='16' />
          <span data-id='user-name'  class='user'></span>
          <span data-id='place-name'  class='title'></span>
          <br />
          <span data-id='place-address'></span>
        </div>

        <div id='win_2' class='iwin' data-type='foreign'>
          <img src='' width='16' height='16' />
          <span data-id='user-name'  class='user'></span>
          <span data-id='place-name' class='title'></span>
          <br />
          <span data-id='place-address'></span>
        </div>


        <!-- // // -->
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Two autocomplete,one map]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible fix. At the end of the `autocomplete.addListener` callback, add the following lines:

```
var username = document.getElementById('name').value;
infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = username;
infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent.innerHTML);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

This will work if you enter a name and then search for a place.

Here is a [JSBin with a working example](http://jsbin.com/bifudoc/3/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Yes works but when inputing 2nd field first infoWindow disappears

Comment: The setContent method of the InfoWindow class accepts either a string or a Node ([docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/info-window#InfoWindow.setContent))

Comment: That's good know @geocodezip, I removed that section from my answer.

Comment: @AlexGarretjones, you need to apply the code in my answer to both autocomplete listeners. I updated the JSBin link.

Answer (score 0):

You are populating the `username` variable **before** the user enters the information.

**Solution:** get it when it is needed (in the autocomplete callback function):

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('state').value = place.name;
    document.getElementById('stateLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('stateLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(9);
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    username = document.getElementById('name').value;  // <============= ** get it here **
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = username;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uvpnxufc/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    },
    zoom: 3
  });
  var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var input2 = document.getElementById('pac-input2');

  var username = document.getElementById('name').value;

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2);

  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
  autocomplete2.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  var infowindowContent2 = document.getElementById('infowindow-content2');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 59.325,
      lng: 18.070
    },
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 50.325,
      lng: 24.070
    },
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker2.setVisible(false);
    var place2 = autocomplete2.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('foreign').value = place2.name;
    document.getElementById('foreignLat').value = place2.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('foreignLng').value = place2.geometry.location.lng();


    if (place2.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place2.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place2.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(9);
    }
    marker2.setPosition(place2.geometry.location);
    marker2.setVisible(true);
    username = document.getElementById('name').value;
    infowindowContent2.children['place-name2'].textContent = username;
    infowindow.open(map, marker2);
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    document.getElementById('state').value = place.name;
    document.getElementById('stateLat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
    document.getElementById('stateLng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(9);
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);
    username = document.getElementById('name').value;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = username;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="StateSide Guess">
    <input id="pac-input2" type="text" placeholder="Foreign Guess">
  </div>
  <div>
    <form action="" class="guess-submit" style="text-align: center">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" value="John Smith" />
      <input type="hidden" id="state" name="state" />
      <input type="hidden" id="stateLat" name="stateLat" />
      <input type="hidden" id="stateLng" name="stateLng" />

      <input type="hidden" id="foreign" name="foreign" />
      <input type="hidden" id="foreignLat" name="foreignLat" />
      <input type="hidden" id="foreignLng" name="foreignLng" />
      <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<div id="infowindow-content2">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon2">
  <span id="place-name2" class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address2"></span>
</div>
```